# Is it possible to rsync a live virtual machine image file?

Tags: rsync, kvm, virsh

I have several virtual machines on KVM. They are mostly stateless, and shutting them down would be impactful and is not ideal.

Is it possible to:

```
rsync /var/lib/libvirt/images/host1.qcow2 user@offsite:/var/lib/backup
```

(As well as dump and rsync their associated domain's XMLs).

These vary in size from ~60GB to ~20GB. Can I expect some sort of corruption, or is this generally harmless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly harmless in your case but you might expect filesystem errors when you try to use them later, so just run fsck on them. journald storage may get corrupted, so your system log may disappear.

If you can remount guest partitions `ro` and run `sync` prior to rsync'ing that will make the process seamless and errors-free but I doubt it's possible.

You can also try sending `-SIGSTOP` to all the writing processes prior to rsyncing, then issue `sync` in your guest, rsync, and send `-SIGCONT` - that will lead to even fewer corruptions.

Comment: Thanks Artem, these hosts simply serve to proxy media traffic between public and private networks, so I'm confident they have a mostly stateless nature.